# Set table collation and make it case insensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database using T-SQL:

```
create database MyDb
on primary ( 
  name = 'MyDb_Data',
  size = 40MB,
)
,
filegroup [FILES] contains filestream ( 
  name = 'MyDb_Files'
)
log on ( 
  name = 'MyDb_Log',
  size = 4MB
);
go
```

How can I set, in this, the collation to latin and case insensitive?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Do you mean "database collation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to use the COLLATE

```
CREATE DATABASE [asdf]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'asdf', FILENAME = N'D:\SQLData\asdf.mdf' , SIZE = 4096KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'asdf_log', FILENAME = N'D:\SQLData\asdf_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
GO
```